# IIS 10 ASP.NET application startup slow next day while using idle timout-out Action: Suspend

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5, iis-10

We are currently using an M2 Large server from Amazon.

In the Advanced Settings of an application pool in IIS 10, we are using these options,

`Idle Time-out Action: Suspend`

`Idle Time-out (minutes): 1`

`Start Mode: OnDemand`

`Recycling Time Interval (minutes) : 1740`

When the application pool is in suspended mode the next day, the startup of the application is still slow. Could we improve the startup while using these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Recycling Time Interval is 1740 minutes or 29 hours.  From https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes ,

> However, since you likely know your environment, it’s best to change this. I recommend setting to a fixed time like 4:00am if you’re on the East coast of the US, 1:00am on the West coast, or whatever seems to make sense for your audience when you have the least amount of traffic. Setting it to a fixed time each day during low traffic times will minimize the impact and also allow you to troubleshoot easier if you run into any issues. If you have multiple application pools it may be wise to stagger them so that you don’t overload the server with a lot of simultaneous recycles

You would probably have to use application initialization (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) and increase your Idle Time Out as well to make sure your app is hot for the first user.

Comment: If we change the recycling time to the evening, the app will  be shutdown at night, but won't come up automatically - correct? This will mean that the app will be booted when the first user opens the application in the morning and will have to wait for 20 seconds.

Comment: See my edit above.  You could recycle at say 8:30 am.  Application initialization loads the app.  An idle timeout of 35 mins makes the app hot at 9 am.

Comment: What if we change `Start Mode: OnDemand` to `Start Mode: AlwaysRunning` and change `Preload Enabled: False` to `Preload Enabled: True`.

Comment: In that case you probably want to set the idle timeout to 0.  Then your app will always be hot.

Comment: We would like to use the suspend function. It looks like the suspend function works while `Start Mode: AlwaysRunning` is on.

Comment: Yes, but you'll face the same problem, I think.  Here's some interesting reading: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/522

Comment: It seems setting `doAppInitAfterRestart: True` in `system.webServer/applicationInitialization` and adding the initializationPages to the collection works. After I recycle the application pool the pages seems to get requested and after some minutes the process worker gets suspended.

Comment: Is that satisfactory?

Comment: Yes, this is satisfactory! I think we can use `Start Mode: OnDemand` instead of `Start Mode: AlwaysRunning`?

Comment: Could you please synopsize the latest configuration?  Thanks.

Comment: The configuration we have now is,

`Idle Time-out Action: Suspend`

`Idle Time-out (minutes): 20`

`Start Mode: OnDemand`

`Recycling Time Interval (minutes) : 1740`

In virtual directory under the site we have now: 
`Preload Enabled: True`
In Configuration Editor under applicationInitalization:
`doAppInitAfterRestart: True`
Added to Collection under the virtual directory:
`InitializationPage: /`

Comment: The body of your comment is missing.

Comment: Sorry, added the body to the comment

Comment: Can you try it overnight and verify?  I like the idle timeout but the recycle time seems high (29 days).  It will preload on wakeup only.  Can you try Recycle Time = whatever gets you to 8:30 am (or whatever) the next day?

Comment: It's the default: 29 hours.

Comment: So it will be suspended for 29 hours and be awakened then or before that in a slow on-demand load?

Comment: Yes, after recycle the right applications are started with application initialization, then after 1 minute of idle time the application pool will be suspended.

Comment: But then aren't you back to the problem in your description above?

Comment: No, because with the `Preload Enabled: True` and the `doAppInitAfterRestart: True` with the `InitializationPage` setup for the applications the applications will be started after a `Recycle`. Without these settings this was not happening.

Comment: Yes, but your recycle is 29 hours.  Until your recycle happens nothing happens.  Is this what  you want?  I think you should reduce your recycle time.

Comment: The problem was that the applications weren't started after a `Recycle`. These settings fixed is. Thanks for pointing to the `Application Initialization`.

Comment: True, the application pool will get suspended with `Idle Time-out Action : Suspend` after a `Idle Time-out (minutes): 1`, so the application pool will only use a minimal amount of CPU and memory, it will start faster than having the `Idle Time-out Action : Terminate`.